# PowerShell Workflow - Hanging

Tags: powershell, workflow

I'm testing out PowerShell workflows, mainly with resuming upon restart. All this code does is write a text file with the date and time. Then it restarts. Then it writes a different text with with the name and date. It also displays 1 line of system information.

```
Write-Host "TESTING WORKFLOW3"

Workflow GetComputerInfo
{
     $computers = "PCNAME-TEST", "PCNAME-TEST2"
 Foreach ($cn in $computers)
 { 
    Write-Output "Now on computer $cn"

    "Current time of writing this file is: $(Get-Date)" | 
        Out-File \\$cn\C$\test.txt -Force

    Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem -PSComputerName $cn

    Restart-Computer -Wait -PSComputerName $cn -Force

    Write-Output "System $cn has now restarted."

    "The system should have restarted. Current time of writing this file is: $(Get-Date)" | 
        Out-File \\$cn\C$\test2.txt -Force
 } 
}   
 GetComputerInfo
```

Problem: Upon restart the computer hangs at this step. It checks things like WinRM, then checks PowerShell connectivity.

[image]

It's sat on this step indefinetely. I've tried running multiple times. Any advice?

Comment: Have you considered waiting for something?  `Restart-Computer -Wait -For WMI` as an example

Comment: I believe it already waits for WMI and WinRM, that last thing it waits for by default is Powershell connectivity. This just always hangs. So how is waiting for WMI going to solve my problem....? Or waiting for Powershell....? (It's already doing that, and I assume it has to progress past this step because if it doesn't I assume my next powershell commands will not work)

Comment: Are these computers in domain network?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on computer environment use additional `-Wait` options. For domain network try use:

```
Restart-Computer -PSComputerName $cn -Wait -For WinRM -Delay 5 -Protocol WSMan -WsmanAuthentication Kerberos
```

Comment: I see. So maybe upon querying that the service is start it wasn't and then just hung afterwards? I've read about -delay and how it specifies a delay between queries in seconds. Does this mean without delay it only actually queried initially and never again? Maybe the initial query didn't succeed, so it just hung?